# Portal.getUser is not working after user logs in

Tags: hook, liferay-6

We are having a problem on Liferay we don't know how to deal with.

We need a Hook filter to catch user requests to a particular URL pattern (which is direct accesses to document library files) as with:

> http://localhost:8080/documents/20181/323505/dddd.pdf/d188618b-56c5-4be6-bf94-548fac22bc24

Key Users are sending this type of links to "consumers", but they need to register a "reader" event into the DDBB so as to know which user reads which document. So we used a hook to intercept requests to this URL pattern. Hook configuration is like:

```
<hook>
 <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
 <servlet-filter>
    <servlet-filter-name>Readership Filter</servlet-filter-name>
    <servlet-filter-impl>
      mypackage.hook.filter.ReadershipFilter
    </servlet-filter-impl>
 </servlet-filter>
 ...
```

and then, Java class implementing the filter is like this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, 
                     ServletResponse servletResponse, 
                     FilterChain filterChain ) 
                     throws IOException, ServletException {

    ...
    try {

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

        User user = PortalUtil.getUser((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest);
    ...
```

The problem is that these links are sent via email, so when the user first hits the web, he is not logged in and "User" is null. But once he logs in, Liferay still intercepts the second call to the url; however, Portal.getUser still gives us a null User, so we can't write the "user reader" because we don't know which user really is.

We have tried to use...

```
<after-filter>Auto Login Filter</after-filter>
```

... in the Hook configuration, with no success at all.

What are we doing wrong?

Many Thanks in advance.

Disclaimer: I've posted this one on [Liferay forum](https://web.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/106308311) as well, so I'll pingback as soon as anybody would answer (however, thx to Olaf, I understand it's not a best practice)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: Thx, Olaf. Now I read about it, I guess it's right.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, a colleague of us found that PortalUtil was not working as expected, since we could access user id by just going to the session information, as with:

```
(String)((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest).getSession()
      .getAttribute("j_remoteuser")
```

Can't figure out why PortalUtil was not able to grab the user info, but anyhow... problem solved.